# 'no such table' error while trying query data from SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database with 3 tables in an android aplication (produtos, lista and items).
But when a try to make a query I get the exception 'no such table items.'

The code of my DatabaseHelper:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE lista(" +
                    "id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                    "nome VARCHAR(50), " +
                    "data VARCHAR(10), " +
                    "total REAL, " +
                    "primary key(id));");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE items( " +
                    "id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                    "lista INT, " +
                    "produto INT, " +
                    "valor REAL, " +
                    "primary key(id));");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE produtos(" +
                "id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                "descricao VARCHAR(100), " +                
                "primary key(id));");
    }
```

I get the exception in this part of the code:

```
String sql = "SELECT i.id, i.valor, i.lista, p.descricao " +
                       "FROM items i " +
                       "INNER JOIN produtos p " +
                       "ON (i.produto = p.id) " +
                       "WHERE (items.lista = ?)";

        try
        {
            Cursor cursor = banco.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{String.valueOf(lista)}); //the exception
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                Item i = new Item();
                i.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                i.setValor(cursor.getDouble(1));
                i.setLista(cursor.getInt(2));
                i.setDescricao(cursor.getString(3));
                l.add(i);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(contexto, e.getMessage(), 100000).show();
        }
```

I create the two other tables and I have no problem with them while quering, I think the error is in the query string but I don't know why.

The strange thing is that apparently I can insert in this table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "WHERE (i.lista = ?)"

You assigned an alias to 'items'.